# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'ProjectName.UserCell'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

Hey guys befor you mark this as a duplicate just please hear me out. I have tried everything related to this topic including adding

self.tableView.registerClass(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

I have also changed my placeholder cell to match the UserCell class

[image: view with placeholder cell changed to UserCell]

Im Not sure what it could be! I get the error :

Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1134700e0) to 'Lightning_Chat.UserCell'

with type SIGBRT not sure what could be going on and ive tried everything please help!

here is table view code :

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    // not casting for some reason 
    let cell : UserCell =  UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle , reuseIdentifier: "cellId") as! UserCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = contacts[indexPath.row].userName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contacts[indexPath.row].score


    if let profileImageUrl = contacts[indexPath.row].picURL {
        let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in


            //download hit an error
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }

        }).resume()
    }


    return cell;
}
```

here is my view did load :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    //irrelevant 
    fetchUsers()
}
```

Comment: **Never** register cells if you are using prototype cells designed in a storyboard.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help guys! ur the reason stackoverflow is the best code help website :)

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate issue, but your code to set the profile image is going to fail if the user scrolls the table view before the image is loaded from the Internet. And you really should cache the images so you don't keeping requesting the same images over and over as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
let cell : UserCell =  UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle , reuseIdentifier: "cellId") as! UserCell
```

Try this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the cell correctly.

Change:

```
let cell : UserCell =  UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle , reuseIdentifier: "cellId") as! UserCell
```

to:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
```

Note that your code is directly creating a `UITableViewCell` which is why you can't cast it. You are bypassing the standard cell reuse as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the step to fix your problem

1. Change your table view content to be dynamic cell, instead of static cell
2. Maintain the code on your viewDidLoad function self.tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId"). Also don't forget to connect table view delegate and datasource
3. On your table view cellForRowAt index path method, don't instantiate the cell directly. Instead use let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!;

Basically that error you got, is because of mix and match the wrong properties on your table view.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes: to 2. I refer to my comment *Never register cells if you are using prototype cells designed in a storyboard* (as the OP clearly does) - to 3. Your suggested line will reliably crash (well actually not exactly in this line)

Comment: Alright, OP obviously want to use the custom cell as UserCell class which I assume inherited from UITableViewCell, so OP need to register it on the tableview and DON'T instantiate it directly from cellForRow method.

Comment: If OP want to use prototype cell, then remove the UserCell class from table view

Comment: No sir, once again: You must not register cells when the cell is designed in storyboard. Registering cells is only required when using extra nibs or create the cell in code. And the crash in 3. occurs because you don't cast the cell to the custom class.

Comment: See my latest reply, I suggested that OP remove the user cell class from the if OP want to use prototype cell. As far my experience registering prototype cell can be done with this code: .register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier); Did it so many times, wonder why you suggest to not use it?

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding: Prototype cells can be one of the predefined types (Basic, Right Detail, Left Detail, and Subtitle) but also `Custom` – that means custom design and custom class. I did never register cells in this case, so it is redundant / needless.